# elastic agfregations get uniq value where clause

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have a query in Elastic search to get unique values for specific field. 
How to get Unique values using where clause.
where field1:xyz, field2:yzx etc

```
{
"size": 20,
"aggs" : {
    "pf" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "platform" }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for aggregations with filters

```
{
    "size":0, // <-- If you are using ES 2.0 or above, setting size=0 will only return aggregations and no results
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "term": {
                            "field1": "xyz"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "term": {
                            "field2": "abc"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "pf": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "platform"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have one more small query. While getting unique platform field, I am getting all the docs also. How to get only platform values to reduce response time.

Comment: Ok Got it. Thanks

Comment: @venkat, please accept the answer if it solves your concerns.